# How to implement Real-time notifications (Pub/Sub) for in-App-Purchases?

Tags: php, android, publish-subscribe

I am trying to update my database according to the push notifications that come from Google when a user purchases or subscribes in my app.For this I will use php.
What will happen is:

1. User makes a subscription in my app.
2. Pub/Sub receives that data and sends a push notification to a link provided by me.
3. Data in database is updated.
   4.The app makes an http request and gets the subscription information.

I  provided an URL for pub sub notifications , what I need is to parse the data, make a request to get the updated data and update the database accordingly .
I know how to make the request

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher');
    $service = new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($client);
     $subscription = $service->purchases_subscriptions->get($package_name,
            $product_id,
            $token);
```

But I don't know how to handle subscription or purchase coming from PubSub and flow accordingly. How should I do it?

Comment: Im not sure which part needs to be done. Is it just 4? Who do you want to notify? You or the user? Whatever it is, show us what you got, so we can help you where you are stuck.